# Emit new value to Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have the following code:

```
this.isUsingGoogleTwoFactor$ = this.user$.pipe(map((user: User) => 
user.isUsingGoogleTwoFactor));
```

Now what I want is to emit new value to `isUsingGoogleTwoFactor$`. I know I can't do this with `observables` but I should use `subjects`. But I do not know exactly how to do it with pipes.

Thanks!

Comment: Please see [Subject.prototype.next()](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subject#next)

Comment: @Rafael Yep saw that but how I can use it with pipes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understad correctly you want this observable to trigger both on changes to the user$, and when you manually trigger it. Then you could do this approach.

```
import { merge, Subject } from 'rxjs';

...

const manuallyTriggered$ = new Subject();
const triggeredFromUser$ = this.user$.pipe(
    map((user: User) => user.isUsingGoogleTwoFactor)
);

this.isUsingGoogleTwoFactor$ = merge(manuallyTriggered$, triggeredFromUser$);
```

And when you want to manually trigger it:

```
manuallyTriggered$.next(true);
```

Comment: I'll check this.

Comment: Hi I tried this:

this.isUsingGoogleTwoFactor$ = merge(this.isUsingGoogleTwoFactorSubject,  this.user$.pipe(mergeMap((user: User) => of(user.isUsingGoogleTwoFactor)))); but I got an error saying: Type 'OperatorFunction<{}, boolean | {}>' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<boolean>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.

Comment: I used BEhaviorSubject instead. But your solution works. Thank you!

Comment: Nice to hear :)

Answer (score 5):

Check [BehaviourSubject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html). It's the kind of Observable that allows you to push new values and keeps track of the last value that it emitted.

An example of how to use it is in that site I linked. but in short, this is how you use it:

```
const observable = new BehaviorSubject("initial value");
```

If at this point a subscriber comes, and executes:

```
observable.subscribe({
    next: (value) => console.log("The value is: ", value)
});
```

Then the output will be:

```
The value is: initial value
```

After that, every time you invoke `next` all the subscribers will receive the notification:

```
observable.next("a new value");
```

will print this in the subscriber:

```
The value is: a new value
```

Comment: How can I use this with pipes?

Comment: You already have it, in my example I called the subject `observable` and in yours you called it `this.user$`. So, whichever part of your app generates the `user$` observable is the one that should use a `BehaviourSubject`